# How do you determine the remaning capacity of a magnetic tape with mt or tar? How much space is in a block?

Tags: tar, compression, archive, scsi, tape

I am currently trying to back up data onto an LTO-4 tape using [`mt-st`](https://github.com/iustin/mt-st)
and gnu `tar` 1.32, but I want to make sure I stop trying to copy things before the tape runs out! LTO-4 nominally has a capacity of 800G or 1.6T compressed. [`tapeinfo -f /dev/nst0 | grep Comp`](https://github.com/zombielinux/MTX) returns

```
DataCompEnabled: yes
DataCompCapable: yes
DataDeCompEnabled: yes
CompType: 0x1
DeCompType: 0x1
```

which I think means that [compression is enabled](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/lto-tape-drive-linux-experience-4175620090/)? Then again, I am adding archives to the tape with `mt-st -f /dev/nst0 eod ; tar -czf /dev/nst0 directoryname`, so I am also compressing that archive with gzip.

In short, I don't know how to visualize how much data the archives on the tape are taking up, they are measured in blocks and I don't know how much data a block consists of. I have copied about 200G of data to the tape already and `mt-st -f /dev/nst0 eod ; mt-st -f /dev/nst0 status ; echo -e "\n" ; mt-st -f /dev/nst0 tell` returns:

```
SCSI 2 tape drive:
File number=1, block number=-1, partition=0.
Tape block size 0 bytes. Density code 0x46 (LTO-4).
Soft error count since last status=0
General status bits on (9010000):
 EOD ONLINE IM_REP_EN


At block 18763534.
```

But `tapeinfo -f | grep MaxBlock` returns `MaxBlock: 16777215`. So it appears I am already passed the maximum block? But `mt-st -f /dev/nst0 rewind ; tar -tzvf /dev/nst0` does return a list of all of the files I copied into that archive and moves the tape to the end of data, so I shouldn't have ran out of any space. From looking at the `mt` manual, I cannot find a way to go to the end of the tape without first writing it.

Here is the rest given by `tapeinfo` if that helps:

```
Vendor ID: 'HP      '
Product ID: 'Ultrium 4-SCSI  '
Revision: 'U57D'
Attached Changer API: No
SerialNumber: 'HU1104ERC3'
MinBlock: 1
MaxBlock: 16777215
SCSI ID: 0
SCSI LUN: 0
Ready: yes
BufferedMode: yes
Medium Type: Not Loaded
Density Code: 0x46
BlockSize: 0
Block Position: 18763534
Partition 0 Remaining Kbytes: 800226
Partition 0 Size in Kbytes: 800226
ActivePartition: 0
EarlyWarningSize: 0
NumPartitions: 0
MaxPartitions: 0
```

Comment: I have no idea whether GNU tar is able to handle unknown tape sizes. `star` works fine when in multi volume mode and the tape driver in the kernel works correctly. Hint: the kernel needs to report EOF correctly while writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaxBlock` from `tapeinfo` means the maximum block size that the drive supports. For example, when you used `tar` command, you might specify the block size by tar `-b` option. This size have the upper limit, and this limit corresponds to `MaxBlock`. On the other hand, `mt-st -f /dev/nst0 tell` shows where tape is. Indeed, if you look at the `Block Position` from `tapeinfo`, this number agrees with the return from `mt-st tell`.

You can try the following bash script that I have created to read the remaining capacity from LTO-CM chip. https://github.com/Kevin-Nakamoto/LTO-CM-Read

Comment: You cannot predict the remaining capacity if the tape uses compression

Comment: Exactly. All we can do is measuring the remaining capacity "after" write process.

Comment: The automatic error correction in LTO drives can consume more space than expected for a write. You need to leave some room for overhead.